# Sync the [async] tags

Tags: support, tag-merge

There seem to be three different tags about asynchronous programming:

- [async](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/async) (69 questions)
- [asynchronous-programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asynchronous-programming) (65 questions)
- [asynchronous](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asynchronous) (3 questions)

I think there is no difference between the three and so they should be merged into a single tag. Keeping [asynchronous-programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asynchronous-programming) makes the most sense to me (even though it's pretty long).

Comment: A cursory glance through the tags shows that several questions are tagged with more than one.

Comment: Not sure if it matters or not, but `async` is a newer keyword in the .Net framework and a quick glance at questions tagged with `async` show a lot of questions to be about the await/async pattern. It might not be suitable to merge that with the other two.

Comment: @Rachel If you want to differentiate between asynchronous programming in general and the `async`-`await` pattern in C# and other languages, then I think [tag:async-await] tag should be created for that (SO uses that).